Response not handled as attachment (i.e. File not downloading) in HTMX
I am fairly new to Django but I've been stuck on a problem for several days. I have been trying to find answers online without any success.
I have a view called CreateReportView where I am trying to use weasyprint to generate a pdf that gets downloaded. In the future I want to be able to save the bytes array to a database, so a user can see the generated reports and then to download them. But a first step is just being able to download the generated pdf. When using the weasyprint write_pdf() method and saving to disc, e.g. to test.pdf, the pdf is ok when opening the file. However, when I try to generate the PDF to a variable and save it in either File- or HTTPresponse as an attachment, I only get text with characters in the browser that looks like this:
%PDF-1.7 % 5 0 obj <> stream xڽXm  6  _ ? 9  IpZ  [(]h   n ܧ p   r d  ή   ױg yy     ( G 1       @     \ ? z     


I have tried everything I can think of, such as changing between Http- and FileResponse, saving the file temporary to the disc, opening it and then passing it to the respons; using a buffer; etc.. I have also tried using the Reportlab library and I get the same problem. To clarify, when I tried using the HttpResponse, I used the following code:
response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'

I saw that someone solved the problem using a buffer (Using Weasyprint to create file response), but it didn't work for me. The code for this is commented in the view below. I get the same problem
I found that someone else solved it by changing a 'traffic-cop' routine, but I cant seem to find the code that needs to be changed (Django - can't download file (showed as text instead)).
Also, when using the inspection mode in Chrome, I saw that the response includes the necessary headers such as content-disposition and and content-type.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need further information.
Thank you in advance!
EDIT: The website also uses Alpine.js and HTMX. There is no HTMX or Alpine.js scripts in the template that gets rendered by the write_pdf method. In my base site, I have some HTMX-attributes as:
<body x-data="{'isModalOpen': false}" hx-boost='True' hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

View file:
from django.core.files import File
from django.db.models import Avg, Count, Case, When, IntegerField, DecimalField
from django.http import HttpResponse, FileResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.views import View
from weasyprint import HTML
from salary.models import Salary

class CreateReportView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, ** kwargs):

        ... # Omitted unrelevant code

        context = context={'results': results, 'results_per_gender': results_per_gender, 'results_per_region': results_per_region, 'results_titles': results_titles}
        rendered_html = render_to_string('report_template.html', context=context)

        # buffer = io.BytesIO()
        # pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html)
        # pdf_file.write_pdf(buffer)
        pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html).write_pdf()
        # buffer.seek(0)
        response = FileResponse(pdf_file, as_attachment=True, filename="test.pdf")
        return response


How are you passing buffer to FileResponse?

@KJ This doesn’t explain why "When using the weasyprint write_pdf() method and saving to disc, e.g. to test.pdf, the pdf is ok when opening the file."

Thanks for both your responses.
@KJ If I understand you correctly, my method would only work if it was a text/pdf and not application/pdf as it is now. What decides if the file is a text or an application file? Is it the contents of the pdf or the library like weasyprint or reportlab? Can I decide it somehow? Do you have an hypothesis why the person in the other link has a text pdf and I have application pdf using the same library to generate it? Maybe it is the version of weasyprint being used?

@KJ
If I understand your suggestion correctly, your suggestion is to do something as follows:

Save the generated pdf to temporary file 2. Save the temporary file to a variable 3. Delete the temporary file to save space. 4. Return the variable that contains the pdf through FileResponse?


@KJ Also, if I want to save the temporary file in the database for the user to get in the future, I would need to do the following (following your BtoAtoB suggestion):

Save generated pdf to temporary file 2. Save the temporary file to a variable 3. Delete the temporary file to save space. 4. Base64 encode the variable 5. Save the variable to my model in the database?


@KJ Another question regarding conversion to string that you mention - where is this happening? I don't really follow this part. If I understand the weasyprint api correctly write_pdf returns bytes. The bytes are passed to the bytes io variable which also handles bytes. When I read about FileResponse - it also handles bytes and says as following in the documentation "Note that if you pass a file-like object like io.BytesIO, it’s your task to seek() it before passing it". Do you mean that the conversion to string happens sometime after this in the background,?

@KJ Thank you though, it clarifies somethings. I am still quite lost and not sure how to handle this question. I tried creating a temporary file locally and then returning the file through FileResponse as: HTML(string=rendered_html).write_pdf('temp.pdf')
response = FileResponse(open("temp.pdf", "rb"), as_attachment=True, filename="temp.pdf")
But I get exactly the same problem when downloading. However, opening temp.pdf on the computer works just fine...

Try FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="test.pdf") with your currently commented out code. If it works for you but you need more clarification, I’ll write up an answer.

@ChukwujiobiCanon Thanks, unfortunately, I get the same problem. :(

Just to be sure:
    buffer = io.BytesIO()     HTML(string=rendered_html).write_pdf(buffer)     buffer.seek(0)     return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="test.pdf")
No extras, just that?

@ChukwujiobiCanon Yes, like that. I copy and pasted your code in the comment just to be sure. Same error. I also tried downgrading Django from 5.0.6 to 4.2, but still same problem.
Code:
'''
buffer = io.BytesIO()
HTML(string=rendered_html).write_pdf(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="test.pdf")
'''

Ok, so I have a url /report/ connected to the view. If I enter tthe full url in the browser - it downloads a pdf as it is supposed to. But if I go through the link which links to the page, it shows in the browser. Any thoughts?

I’ll investigate more but brace yourself, it might take me another hour.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I think I solved it now. I used hx-boost=true (htmx) as an attribute in my body tag in my base page on the site. When I removed it, it seems to be working now when following a link. I realize now I should have given these extra details, but I didn't think they mattered in this case. Thanks for all your assistance.

Fair enough :). Confirm if it was your original proposal with BytesIO that ended up working. The one I asked you to try and try again. I’m really curious.

@ChukwujiobiCanon Yes, it was. It works fine with BytesIO like the one you asked me to try again now :)

Ohh I see… with the hx-boost attribute, the innerHTML swap strategy is used by default on the target which is the body tag. The effect is that the PDF content is flushed into the body tag in its binary format. Browser’s cannot render PDF this way. If you understood this but need more clarification, I will write an answer to clarify.

weasyprint.HTML.write_pdf() returns a bytes instance when invoked without arguments but it returns None when invoked with argument. If invoked with a file instance or an str path to a file as target, it writes the PDF bytes data to the target. There is nothing wrong with what you were doing all along on the Server.
buffer = BytesIO()
HTML(string=html).write_pdf(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="test.pdf")

The problem was completely Client side. When you add HTMX attribute hx-boost="true" to any HTML tag like so:
<div hx-boost="true">
What HTMX does is that it boosts normal anchor and Form tags to use AJAX. This has a good effect which is that if the user does not have javascript enabled, the site will continue to work.
A GET request will push the request URL onto the Browser History Stack (if from anchor tags). The response body will be used to swap the innerHTML of the body tag of the page.
If the response body is valid HTML, Browsers can render it just fine. But since it isn’t, that was the problem. Browser’s cannot render PDF when the bytes of the PDF is used to swap the innerHTML of the body tag of the page hence the result you got:
%PDF-1.7 % 5 0 obj <> stream xڽXm  6  _ ? 9  IpZ  [(]h   n ܧ p   r d  ή   ױg yy     ( G 1       @     \ ? z     


To complete the response and let the browser handle download on its own without attempting to swap the innerHTML of the body tag of the page with the response body, add hx-swap="none" attribute to the section involved in making the request:
<div hx-boost="true" hx-swap="none">

Ah, so basically the hx-boost is on the page where OP is calling the view to create the PDF from? That makes sense now, would be great if the OP edited to clarify that properly.

@AbdulAzizBarkat good note. But OP did in the last edit which is why I offered to write an answer: "In my base site [?HTML], I have some HTMX-attributes as..."

The thing is I misconstrued that as the  hx-boost being part of the page rendered as PDF. I was wondering how that would be relevant since the JavaScript won't run in that case.

Thank you very much for the answer and clarification. It makes a lot more sense now. I have now a better understanding of the issue and if it happens again, I'll have a better luck finding a solution for the issue :) I marked your answer as accepted, but unfortunately I could not give you an upvote since I don't have enough reputation on the site.

Welcome to stackoverflow @samuelh. As long as you are a contributing member of the community, I assure you that you will enjoy it here and you will gain more reputation as you go. All you need is the patience to learn.

I failed to mention that I was using HTMX on the page. In my base page, I used hx-boost=true (htmx) as an attribute in my body tag. When removing the attribute, it seems to be working as it is supposed to. I realize now I should have given these extra details, but I didn't think they mattered in this case. Thanks for all the assistance.

If that really was the issue you should edit the question and add that detail in (as a sample of the HTML being rendered). The answer should simply explain that removing that will solve the issue.

Ohh I see… with the hx-boost attribute, the innerHTML swap strategy is used by default on the target which is the body tag. The effect is that the PDF content is flushed into the body tag in its binary format. Browser’s cannot render PDF this way. If you understood this but need more clarification, I will write an answer to clarify.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I have edited the question with the information as requested.

@ChukwujiobiCanon A clarification as an answer would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
